# How to export menu icons in high quality using Illustrator

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, adobe-illustrator, android-icons

I made simple menu icons which look the way I want them to look when in Illustrator, but when I place them in my app they look pixelated and bad.

Here is it in my app (as you can see, the text is not pixelated):

[image]

This is how it looks in Illustrator (I cut the icons and pasted them next to the other two, that's why the background is in different color):

[image]

I made the icons on 72x72 px canvas and exported them as .png file.
I am using Android Studio to make my app, and use simple 
`android:background="@drawable/back_button"` to set the image/icon for the ImageButton.

Answer (score 1):

I never try Illustrator to put icons, but I am directly download icons from [flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/) that provides any type of file and size too

Two way to get different canvas file in android studio.

> 1. Android Studio-> File-> Image Asset or Vector Asset

upload your file and set as you need

> 2. [Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C0&name=ic_example)

From this you can get directly res folder with different canvas image.
Mostly I prefere first.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah..but I'm interested in making my own icons, that's the point of the question: how to make them look good on small screen, not how to use icons from different sites. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

these icons as shown in fig. have a background color assigned by you in illustrator, no matter these are exported as png format or jpg!

First go back to illustrator and try to make background of images transparent as you assigned greyish color, tell me if it works. That's great you are making icons for yourself. Good work.

Comment: I made the icons on separate Illustrator file...so first of all I made the design of the app with all the icons on it, then I copy/pasted them into another file and exported them as .png

I left the background so you can see it more clearly because the icons are pure white and you probably wouldn't see them if I put them here like that

Comment: then just upload your image to android asset studio link and it give return you output with diff. folders just paste them in your multiple drawable folders in android studio - https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_example

Answer (score 0):

I think when you save the file please try to save it (SVG) format & then place it.